# Finding a bijection from the set of all infinite series of elements from the set ${{0,1,2,3}}$ to all infinite series of the set ${{0,1}}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Every infinite sequence of the elements of the first group represents a number in base 4, every sequence in the second set represents a number in base 2, the bijection is trivial. However, I'm pretty sure there's an easier way, I just can't think of it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are not satisfied with your solution ?!! looks already easy, no ?

Comment: Be careful with series that are only '3' : 0.99999... = 1. Just one little trick to find here

Comment: Group the sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s by twos. and send $00$ to $0$, $01$ to $1$, $10$ to $2$, $11$ to $3$. This is *related* to base $2$ to base $4$ conversion, but we don't need to think of the sequences as representing real numbers. That's an irrelevancy, and such an approach would force us to deal with non-uniqueness. (I gave inverse of the mapping, we can give also describe the mapping directly.)

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you elaborate on the non-uniqueness? What sequence can cause a problem through my answer?

Comment: Mark, writing the real numbers in binary we have that $\frac12=0.10000\ldots=0.01111\ldots$ which are two different sequences. (Also סדרה = sequence, טור = series.)

Comment: (Also, I think this is another duplicate.)